# how to pivot columns and rows in databricks apache using scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, databricks

im trying to pivot row to column. Im using pivot function but when i use it it just gives me the same exact database without any changes. Code runs fine without any errors , but i would like to reformat the data and add column attribute  and value as shown below. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
 // current database table

    Census_block_group  B08007e1    B08007m1    B08007e2    B08007m2
    010010201001          291         95         291         95
    010010201002          678        143         663         139
```

// what i need

```
    Census_block_group   attribute      value
     010010201001           B08007e1      678
```

//code

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext

spark.conf.set("spark.sql.pivotMaxValues", 999999)

 val df = censusBlocks.toDF
df.groupBy("B08007e1").pivot("census_block_group")
display(df)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are actually trying to do is in fact an "unpivot" rather than a pivot. Spark does not have an unpivot function. Instead you can use the stack function.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val unPivotDF = df.select($"Census_block_group",
expr("stack(4, 'B08007e1', B08007e1, 'B08007m1', B08007m1, 'B08007e2', B08007e2, 'B08007m2', B08007e2) as (attribute,value)"))
unPivotDF.show()
```

You can find more details about the using the stack function here - https://sparkbyexamples.com/how-to-pivot-table-and-unpivot-a-spark-dataframe/

Answer (score 0):

You actually want to 'Transpose' not the 'Pivot'. Here is another solution(Sorry a bit lengthy) :-)

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StringType
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Column, DataFrame, SparkSession}

object Stackoverflow3 {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("Test").master("local").getOrCreate()

    val df = <YOUR ORIGINAL DATAFRAME>

    val transposed = transform(df, Array("Census_block_group"))

    transposed
      .withColumn("Attribute", col("ColVal.col1"))
      .withColumn("Value", col("ColVal.col2"))
      .drop("ColVal")
      .show()
  }

  def transform(df: DataFrame, fixedColumns: Array[String]): DataFrame = {

    val colsToTranspose = df.columns.diff(fixedColumns)

    val createCols = {

      colsToTranspose.foldLeft(Array.empty[Column]) {
        case (acc, name) => acc.:+(struct(lit(name).cast(StringType), col(name).cast(StringType)))
      }

    }

    df
      .withColumn("colVal", explode(array(createCols: _*)))
      .select(Array("Census_block_group", "colVal").map(col): _*)
  }

}
```